# findviewbyid returns null in fragment even though view inflated properly

Tags: android, android-fragments, findviewbyid

I know there are alot of these cases, but my problem is that i did everything right (as much as I know) but the findviewbyid method still returns null

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

This is the stacktrace

```
rootView = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);

if (container == null) {
    return null;
}


mFloatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
Logoutbutton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);


Logoutbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
mFloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(this);


return rootView;}
```

the .setonclicklistener throws the error since the buttons are null

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.MapsFragment">

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_camera_alt_black_24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
      />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Log Out"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="17dp" />

</com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and these are the buttons

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                             at com.example.sanchez.worldgramproject.Fragments.MapsFragment.onViewCreated(MapsFragment.java:224)
                                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1315)
                                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentsToInvisible(FragmentManager.java:2323)
                                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2136)
                                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2092)
                                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1998)
                                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:709)
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
01-31 21:33:00.746 14460-14939/com.example.sanchez.worldgramproject I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 91 with tag 3000110100000000{805310721,0} uid -1, pid: 14460, getuid(): 10248
01-31 21:33:00.876 14460-14939/com.example.sanchez.worldgramproject I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 77
01-31 21:33:00.966 14460-14460/com.example.sanchez.worldgramproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                      Process: com.example.sanchez.worldgramproject, PID: 14460
                                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                          at com.example.sanchez.worldgramproject.Fragments.MapsFragment.onViewCreated(MapsFragment.java:224)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1315)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentsToInvisible(FragmentManager.java:2323)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2136)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2092)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1998)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:709)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

this is the stacktrace.

EDIT!

The problem has been found. It didnt work because the buttons arent necessarily under the "RelativeLayout" rootview but under the "MapsView" root.
Since i was inflating the relativelayout, because of some reason it couldn't inflate the buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call super.onCreate in onCreateView. Those are wildly different methods, and definitely not correct. (You should NOT call super.onCreateView either though)

Why can't container be null? Any specific reason? I've never seen this logic before, and don't know what it'll help (most likely nothing).

This code will work:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);

    mFloatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    Logoutbutton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);

    Logoutbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mFloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    return rootView;
}
```

EDIT:

Try and read the stacktrace that you posted.

This line clearly says it all:

```
com.example.sanchez.worldgramproject.Fragments.MapsFragment.onViewCreated(MapsFragment.java:224)
```

Your code is crashing in the "onViewCreated" method, not "onCreateView" (again, different methods).
It even has a specific line number in the code for reference.

Try and post your FULL Fragment class code, it's very hard to help you if you only give partial data.

Comment: thanks! i didnt notice since i was changing my activity into a fragment.

Comment: but the problem is still there... the findviewbyid still returns null

Comment: Are you sure the XML you posted is from the "activity_maps.xml" file? That's the one you're trying to inflate.

If the issue persists, then try to post the FULL stacktrace, and we can see if it might be some other issue causing your exceptions.

Comment: i posted the error stacktrace (or should i post more?) in the edits

Comment: Is there no further way of finding the problem?

Comment: or could it be that another part of the code triggeres this?

Comment: it works for me now, as i said the error has to do with Mapsview (I didnt notice that when i wanted to get a sample of the error stacktrace i put the .setonclicklistener to view created just to test if it would work, thats why its crashing in viewcreated)